# jQuery AJAX and functions in a CFM file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have been searching for this for about 3 days now and I still cannot find the proper answer to my question.

I apologize if this question has been previously asked. Please share with me a link to the proper answer.

**Question.**
Is it possible to use jQuery AJAX to call functions that are in a `somefile.cfm` (not `.cfc`)page?

My scenario is as follows:

I have a lot of functions in `somefile.cfm`, one of them is `abc`. I am trying the following jQuery code to call `function abc` located at `somefile.cfm`, from `index.cfm` and to get its response as a `json` string.

**index.cfm**

```
...
$.ajax({
  url: 'somefile.cfm',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {method: abc. name: 'don'},
  success: function(res){
     alert(res);
  }
});
```

**somefile.cfm**

```
<cffunction name="abc" returntype="any" returnFormat="json">
  <cfargument name="name" required="yes" type="string">

    <cfset text['name'] = name>
    <cfset jsonvar = serializeJSON(text)>
    <cfreturn jsonvar>
</cffunction>
```

Now when I do the call, I just get a blank response. It seems like the function is not being called. I do not get any error.

It is possible? or do I need to convert this page to coldfusion component `cfc file`? Please help. I need your expertise.

Thanks.

Comment: No, you cannot call ColdFusion functions like that from a .cfm file. The best way to handle returning data like this is by using a CFC.

Comment: @scott, did you downvote my answer?  I was saying you could call it that way with some additional code on the cfm page but not optimal.

Comment: @ScottStroz thanks for the comment. Now, if I change it to a `cfc file` and make every function `access="remote"`, how will I handle security? Will it be more vulnerable to XSS attacks?

Comment: Yes, I did. Giving answers you know are not the best way is counterproductive and will get down votes form me.

Comment: @rob How would you handle security if you try to run a method in a .cfm file called form AJAX? Handling security for something like this is a different topic, as such, should be a different question. However, simply asking how to do security for AJAX calls would be way too broad of a question.

Comment: Ok scott, I reworded.  This answers his question noting not being the best way and gives the better approach.  It's up to the poster to implement best practices

Comment: @SethT It should be up to us to promote best practices and not even mention poor ones. All that does is promote laziness and produce bad developers.

Comment: People who do not know better come here to get good answers to problems from people who are supposed to know better. Suggesting bad practices, and then saying it is up to the poster to implement best practices is ridiculous.

Comment: I told why it wasn't working, so they could learn how the language works.  Then said the better way and why.  That's learning, not blindly doing something because someone said to do it that way.  Or maybe I should just not answer the question and say use a more modern language

Comment: You basically said, 'Here is the way you should do it. If you can't do it that way (for whatever reason) here is the wrong way to do it'. Most developers dealing with an unfamiliar situation will take the path of least resistance, which, in many cases (including this one) is often the wrong path. Lets keep them on the right path.

Comment: I do see your point and we could argue this all day, but knowing that a function in a cfm doesn't get auto called this way will help the user understand the language more.  That was my only point in doing so.

Comment: @ScottStroz thanks for everything. I have moved my functions to a cfc file. I can now called any function using `$.ajax({});` . My problem now is that this does not work at all in my QA server. I am not sure if it has to do with the fact that dev environment runs IIS cf9 and QA environment is linux CF9... I know file names are case-sensitive in Linux, but this is not the case here. When I call a function, I get back the whole page content.. when I use the url (on browser) to call a function, the same thing happens.. I get the whole code..but when I use `<cfinvoke>` it works just fine. weird?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should use cfcs for this

If for some reason you can't do the above, you would need to add a cfscript block on the cfm page to call the function.  You could have a case or an if statement to call the abc function based off what is passed from jquery.  Again, not recommended.

Answer (score -1):

If you call a .cfm file with ajax then whatever the page normally outputs is what gets returned to the caller. If you use cfoutput tags around your JSON returned by the function you should be able to achieve your desired result. Since you're creating a POST your variables will be available in the FORM scope. Once you have hold of FORM.method you know what function to call with FORM.name. Output the result of that call. Here's an example: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2009/03/17/Simple-example-of-loading-a-ColdFusion-query-with-jQuery

Comment: Why would you offer an answer you know is not the best way to do things? That is counterproductive.

Comment: Scott I don't know what would be the best way for Rob. I believe he can weigh the pros and cons from multiple options and choose the method that suits his situation. I don't think providing more information is counterproductive.

Comment: Providing him bad information is, indeed, counterproductive. Teach people bad methods, they will continue to do them that way for a long time to come. How does the old saying go, 'Just because you can, doesn't mean that you should.'

Comment: 'No one would teach you to do it this way...', yet, you just did.

Comment: Scott, I'm not sure why you think using a cfc is the best way and using a cfm is a bad way. Please elaborate on that. Cfcs are just a way to organize your code. I find them useful and use them extensively, but there are other ways equally valid.  I think it's good to know 3 or 4 ways to do something. I don't think creating an AJAX/JSON endpoint using a cfm is wrong or bad. Please make a cogent argument to support your position.

Comment: You stated that no one would teach using a .cfm file as an endpoint for AJAX/JSON. Why do you think that is? I would hazard a guess it is because it is the wrong way to do it. You are correct, it is nice to know more than one way to skin a cat, but in this case, there is really only one way. If I asked how to drive in a screw, would it be acceptable to say 'No one would tell you to do it this way, but use a hammer'? No, it would not. Use the right tool, for the job. Returning JSON from ColdFusion? The right tool is CFCs